# Change font size for ion-searchbar input in Ionic 5

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic5

How do I change the font size of `ion-searchbar` input? Could anyone please help.

```
<ion-searchbar></ion-searchbar>
```

Here's what I tried but this does not work

```
.searchbar-input {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

Please refer to the working example which I created in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-ionsearchbar-styling?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**In Ionic 5**

> *global.scss*

```
ion-searchbar {
    .searchbar-input-container {
        input{
            font-size: 14px !important;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**This my solution in Ionic 5**:

Global.css

```
.searchbarinput {
    input{
       font-size: 20px !important;  
    }
}
```

In search page:

```
<ion-searchbar #searchbar (ionInput)="getProdForSearch($event)" class="searchbarinput" placeholder="Buscar produtos..." search-icon="search-sharp"></ion-searchbar>
```

Comment: Why is this solution doesn't work on the component's scss page?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you have `<style>` tag within your home template file? Angular (what Ionic has underneath) template compiler doesn't allow it and will remove any `<style>` tag you add.

If you have a global .css or .scss file (e.g. index.scss) than you can simply put your `.searchbar-input` style there, and it should work.

Another way I can think of is, adding [`encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation) to your `HomePage` component, which would be not ideal or could break some things, but still should work.

Check the demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-ionsearchbar-styling-vda1eu

What I mean is this:

**home.ts**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.scss'], // added
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None // added
})
export class HomePage { /*... */ }
```

**home.scss**

```css
.searchbar-input {
  font-size: 10px !important;
}
```